# What does WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION do?

Tags: c++, windows

I am reading the definition of the header file **winapifamily.h** and notice the following definition of the `WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION`:

```
#define WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(Partitions)     (Partitions)
```

And the general usage of the macro (as an example) is the following:

```
#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_APP)
```

Now I am so confused, it seems that it is equivalent to

```
#if WINAPI_PARTITION_APP
```

What's the point of having the `#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(...)` at all?

This is the relevant section of the *winapifamily.h* header file:

> ```
> /*
>  * Header files use the WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION macro to assign one or
>  * more declarations to some group of partitions.  The macro chooses
>  * whether the preprocessor will emit or omit a sequence of declarations
>  * bracketed by an #if/#endif pair.  All header file references to the
>  * WINAPI_PARTITION_* values should be in the form of occurrences of
>  * WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(...).
>  *
>  * For example, the following usage of WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION identifies
>  * a sequence of declarations that are part of both the Windows Desktop
>  * Partition and the Windows-Phone-Specific Store Partition:
>  *
>  *     #if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP | WINAPI_PARTITION_PHONE_APP)
>  *     ...
>  *     #endif // WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP | WINAPI_PARTITION_PHONE_APP)
>  *
>  * The comment on the closing #endif allow tools as well as people to find the
>  * matching #ifdef properly.
>  *
>  * Usages of WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION may be combined, when the partitition definitions are
>  * related.  In particular one might use declarations like
>  * 
>  *     #if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_APP) && !WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP)
>  *
>  * or
>  *
>  *     #if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_APP) && !WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_PHONE_APP)
>  *
>  * Direct references to WINAPI_PARTITION_ values (eg #if !WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION_...)
>  * should not be used.
>  */ 
> #define WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(Partitions)     (Partitions)
> ```

Comment: I'd guess abstraction. It's like having `const int MAX_WIDTH = 1024;`. Sure, the operation implemented by the macro may be a no-op *now.* But was it always a no-op, and will it always be?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose a file contain code which can be used in metro app
So the header will define

```
WINAPI_FAMILY = WINAPI_PARTITION_APP

=>WINAPI_FAMILY_DEKSTOP_APP has value of 2

#define WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(Partition)  ((WINAPI_FAMILY & Partition) == Partition)
```

The macro will check what is type of API family

Now suppose u want write code that only works under metro environment, so

```
#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_APP)
    your code for metro application
#endif
```

Substituting values

```
WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_APP) => ((2 & 2) == 2
```

Now if user wants to use for metro code they have to define

Why indirection required
`WINAPI_FAMILY = WINAPI_PARTITION_APP`

```
3 = >  00 11     (both desktop & metro)
2 =>   00 10     (metro apis)
1  =>  00 01     (desktop)
```

this AND function macro is used, because if `WINAPI_FAMILY is 3`, means both apis can be used
`#define WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(Partition)`, then u can specify Partition = 2, 3
and doing (3 & 1) or (3& 2) == 1
that means if `WINAPI_FAMILY = 3`, u can use both (desktop or metro apis)
Thats why anding is required

Comment: This doesn't address the question, why we have to use the indirection `#if WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(WINAPI_PARTITION_APP)` instead of `#if WINAPI_PARTITION_APP`.

Comment: It is interesting to see that your definition of is different than what I have on my machine. Could you provide a bit more information which Windows OS version you are running? And maybe what project are you creating?

Answer (score 1):

They're now defining an API which may support further intelligence in the future. E.g. they might define `WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP` as `(2 | WINAPI_PARTITION_DEPRECATED)` in the future, and have `WINAPI_FAMILY_PARTITION(x)` check the `WINAPI_PARTITION_DEPRECATED` bit in `x`. This sort of future flexibility (for Microsoft) wouldn't be allowed if developers were allowed assume that `WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP` would expand to a single Integer Constant Expression.